# get_posts using a multidimensional array and 2 meta keys

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get posts from the meta keys: `sgt_slide` and `sgt_slide_home`. The problem is that the function `get_posts` is resulting me an array with an object contained only from `sgt_slide` (post type is post), despite the fact `sgt_slide_home` (post type is attachment) meets the requirements for the query to be displayed.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'sgt_slide',
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'sgt_slide_home',
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'no_found_rows' => true, //exclude unnecessary paging calculations
    'numberposts' => -1,
    );
$slides = get_posts($args);
var_dump($slides);
```

RESULT is

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Post)[309]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Post)[309]
  1 => 
    object(WP_Post)[309]
   .
   .
   // should read also the posts with meta key sgt_slide_home
```

In the `postsmeta` table the posts from `sgt_slide` (post type = post) and posts from `sgt_slide_home` are visible, but it reads only the posts from `sgt_slide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're querying posts and attachments, you'll have to include `inherit` in the `post_status` array:

```
'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'inherit' )
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but still showing only one post. And checked, the other attachments, there posts had been published and they are published. BTW, how can I check to be sure that attachments are published status.

Comment: Attachments always inherit the parent post's status. Therefore, in the DB, they have the status inherit. Did you add `post_type => array( 'post', 'attachment' )` to your query?

Comment: Indeed, this is what it was missing `post_type => array( 'post', 'attachment' )`